# Listing unique author contributions

Tags: author, front-matter

I am preparing a manuscript using this template (https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support/see-where-our-services-will-take-you/18782940).

The template demonstrates how to add a statement of author contribution when all authors contributed equally. But in my case, each author made unique contributions. How can I add these unique contributions in an equivalent manner to the style used in the template?

Here is the code up to the section in the template regarding authorship:

```
\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}% Style for submissions to Nature Portfolio journals
%%\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}% American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-vancouver,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Vancouver Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style 
%%\documentclass[sn-chicago]{sn-jnl}% Chicago-based Humanities Reference Style
%%\documentclass[default]{sn-jnl}% Default
%%\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

%%%% Standard Packages
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@author}{\@author\show\@thanks}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%


%\jyear{2021}%

%% as per the requirement new theorem styles can be included as shown below
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

    \author*[1,2]{\fnm{Author1} \sur{Author1}}\email{email@gmail} \equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
    
    \author[2,3]{\fnm{Author2} \sur{Author2} }\email{email@gmail} \equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
    
    \author[1,2]{\fnm{Author3} \sur{Author3}}\email{email@gmail} \equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
    
    
    \affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
    
    \affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\end{document}
```

I want to reproduce the function of `\equalcontent` (a symbol next to the author's name with an explanation for the symbol that populates below the lists of affiliations and emails) but I want a unique symbol and unique text for each author (e.g. conceptualization for author1, resources and investigation for author2). I have tried to use \thanks, but can't seem to get it to do what I want (perhaps improper placement?).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You could also look at other papers or ask the editor how it should be done. Sometimes there is an "Author Contributions" section in the end.